# How can I get a list of SQVI queries by User ID?

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-query

Just as some background, I intend to write an Excel add-in with .NET that can execute queries from an SAP system.

Thus, I'm looking for a list of function modules for SAP's SQVI transaction. I can't seem to find much information about them; the few forum posts I had found before seem to have gone into the internet oblivion.

Specifically, I want to be able to look up the queries created by a user and then display the results in Excel. I can manage the Excel manipulation as well as remotely executing SAP function modules; I simply can't find which SQVI function modules I need to execute.

Update: I did find [this post](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1535121) which directed me to search for function modules in the AQGF group (function modules starting with RSAQ*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL_CATALOG, it seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

As told already by tomdemuyt, you have now found the function to get the required data.
To browse around and get more further data, goto transaction SE93, enter Transaction id SQVI, go to development class or package SQUE, then browse this package with SE80 / have a look at the hierarchy of objects, function groups in special.
Then you see many function groups, but one of them is AQRC to which the mentioned function module RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL_CATALOG belongs.

Answer (score 0):

A list of SQVI Queries by User can be found simply using the following selections in transaction SE16N for table AQLTS.

- AQLTS-CLAS = ‘SYSTQV*’
- AQLTS-HEAD = ‘X’

It is not the ideal way to retrieve the data, because a single field (AQLTS-TEXT) must be parsed for the userID:reportID, but it brings what is needed together in one table.